# Fourier transform of $\exp(-\cosh(x))$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I am trying to compute the Fourier transform
$$
\hat{g}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-\cosh(x)}e^{-2i\pi \xi x} dx
$$
of the function $g(x)=\exp(-\cosh(x))$.

Are there any standard substitution tricks for such type of integrals?

Comment: Maple says it is $$2 K_{2 i \pi \xi}(1)$$where $K_\nu$ is a modified Bessel functions of the second kind.

Answer (score 2):

The modified Bessel function of the second kind, $K_\alpha$ has an integral  representation given by

$$K_\alpha(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-x\cosh(t)}\cosh(\alpha t)\,dt$$

for $\text{Re}(x)>0$.

Now, let $\hat g(\xi)$, $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$, be given by

$$\begin{align}
\hat g(\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\cosh(x)}e^{-i2\pi \xi x}\,dx\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh(t)} \cos(2\pi |\xi| t)\,dt\\\\
&=2\int_0^\infty e^{-\cosh(t)}\cosh(i2\pi |\xi| t)\,dt\\\\
&=2K_{i2\pi |\xi|}(1)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. ;-)